query param in swaggo. Error: can not parse router comment "/books?genre={id} [get]
my route would be like this:
book.GET("/test", bookService.GetAllBook)
and then inside the GetAllBook(), check if i have query param in the route
id := c.Request.URL.Query().Get("id")
if id != "" {
  GetAllBookByGenreId(id)
  return
}
//get all book

how do i specified routes that have query parameter?
//
// @Router /books [get]
GetAllBook()


// @Param    genre    query     int  true  "genre search by id"
// @Router /books?genre={id} [get]     <- Error: can not parse router comment "/books?genre={id} [get]
GetAllBookByGenreId()


I think the @Param is already correct, just need modify the @Router
// @Param genre query int true "genre search by id"
// @Router /books [get] 

